# Cron Expect Script

Tags: unix, cron, expect

I'm trying to schedule an expect script that I have written with Cron. It is not working as expected. This is my code, my entry in the cron file, and the shell file containing the command to run the script. Any help is appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

# Set timeout
set timeout 1

# Set the user and pass
set user "user"
set pass "pass"

# Get the lists of hosts, one per line
set f [open "hosts.txt"]
set hosts [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

# Get the commands to run, one per line
set f [open "commands.txt"]
set commands [split [read -nonewline $f] "\n"]
close $f

# Iterate over the hosts
foreach host $hosts {
    # Establish ssh conn
    spawn ssh $user@$host
    expect "password:"
    send "$pass\r"  

    # Iterate over the commands
     foreach cmd $commands {
        expect "$ "
        send "$cmd\r"
        expect "password:"
        send "$pass\r"
        expect "$ "
     }
}
```

---

```
0,15,30,45 * * * * /home/car02fv/updatelogs.sh #fetch application logs (dbg,api,ch)
```

---

```
#!/bin/sh
rm goxsd1697/* goxsd1698/* goxsd1699/* goxsd1700/* | /home/car02fv/getlogs.sh
```

Comment: Have you checked what error you are getting?

Comment: @PradyumnaMajumder I'm not sure how I can check that.

Comment: `0,15,30,45 * * * * /home/car02fv/updatelogs.sh >/tmp/cron_out 2>&1` replace this instead of what you have in the crontab. and then check the file `/tmp/cron_out` by `vi /tmp/cron_out` . you will get to see the error. Then debug your code accordingly.

Comment: I edited my last comment a bit, please check

Comment: @PradyumnaMajumder okay, I have made the edit. I will check what bug I'm receiving.

Comment: Also if you are checking after every 15 minutes: you can use `*/15 * * * * /home/car02fv/updatelogs.sh >/tmp/cron_out 2>&1` instead of what you are using now

Comment: Don't forget to `read -nonewline` while getting the hosts. Otherwise you're trying to `spawn ssh $user@` with empty host.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer comes from the discussion I had with Camilo above*.

To check the error log and running the script every 15 minutes,

`*/15 * * * * /home/car02fv/updatelogs.sh >/tmp/cron_out 2>&1`

was `run` to check the output file `/tmp/cron_out`, using

`vi /tmp/cron_out`

Also, you need to give permission to the file by `chmod u+x /home/car02fv/updatelogs.sh` to make the script executable.

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing the full path to the files you need to read. Cron scripts usually have PWD as `/`.

Assuming the "hosts.txt" and "commands.txt" are in `/home/car02fv`, you can do

```
0,15,30,45 * * * * cd /home/car02fv && ./updatelogs.sh
```

---

However, this is more robust: assuming you keep those text files in the same place as the script file: add to the expect script (near the top)

```
set dir [file dirname [info script]]
```

then, open the files like this:

```
set hostfile [file join $dir hosts.txt]
if {![file exists $hostfile]} {error "$hostfile does not exist"}
set f [open $hostfile]

# ...
set cmdfile [file join $dir commands.txt]
if {![file exists $cmdfile]} {error "$cmdfile does not exist"}
set f [open $hoscmdfiletfile]
```

and the cron entry stays like you have it.

---

BTW, ".sh" is a misleading file extension for an expect file.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
rm goxsd1697/* goxsd1698/* goxsd1699/* goxsd1700/* | /home/car02fv/getlogs.sh
sleep 120
done
```